# Handle second click on card view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design

Okay, I'm just trying to handle the second click on a `CardView`.

For example, Now when I click on the `CardView`, It will change background color for the `CardView`. Also, it should change the image in the `ImageView`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Also remove either the Kotlin or Java tag. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question: you wanna ask how to prevent from multiple click/tap on a view, if yes then you can handle it by adding following method into your Utility class

```
public static void avoidMultipleTapping(View view) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(() -> view.setEnabled(true), 1000);
}
```

if you want to say something else you can comment below over my answer.